# How to skip first row when writing data from serial port?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

My Python script writes the serial data to an existing CSV file. I am trying to skip the first row from the writer because some random garbage characters always get printed initially. Any easy way to use as an alternative?

```
import serial
import sys
import os

def writer():
try:
    ser = serial.Serial('COM10', baudrate=9600)
    ser.flushInput()

    while True:

        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        print(ser_bytes) 
        file = open("A.csv", "a")
        file.write(str(ser_bytes))
        file.close()          

    ser.close
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
writer()
```

I want to append the serial data to my existing CSV file *without* the initial garbage characters.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading pyserial version to 2.5 might solve the problem:

```
pip uninstall pyserial
pip install "pyserial==2.5"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Anyway I solved my problem I only add some variable with boolean values and use if else condition inside while to read the first line.